# Boot "hangs" when NVIDIA binary driver is installed

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xubuntu, 15.04, xfce

#### THE BACKGROUND

Installed a fresh version of Xubuntu 15.04 and started up a game (Team Fortress 2), to my surprise it ran horribly even though I have a GTX 970.

My system apparently recognized the 970, so I went into `Softwares & Updates` and found out that I was using the Nouveau display driver, so I switched it to the proprietary NVIDIA binary recommended driver and applied then rebooted my system.

#### THE PROBLEM

Once it reached the Xubutu logo screen, where it has the loading circle, all I saw was that loading circle, and a blue background behind it, the rest was black, other than a loading bar with the words "Control + C to cancel system file check", not too surprised, I didn't press anything and left it to do it's thing. I came back about an hour later with a black screen, as if the PC was off, but it wasn't. I rebooted using the physical button and went into the `grub` menu and from there dropped to the `root` shell and uninstalled the driver using firstly `mount -o remount,rw /` and then `apt-get --purge remove nvidia-*` and then I hit `reboot`.

The system started up, and I was logged in, normally, as if nothing was happened, I opened the `Softwares & Updates` window and saw that the driver was set back to the Nouveau one, I guess that happened because I deleted the NVIDIA ones. So then, I google a bit and install some `ppa's` for drivers. Namely `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa -y` and then `sudo apt-get update` and finally `sudo apt-get install nvidia-352`, the 352 being the version I got from the official NVIDIA site. Low and behold, I reboot, and the exact same thing happens. (Read paragraph 3 again).

So after I do the exact same thing, I think maybe it was just a fluke that the games weren't running so well, so I start one up again, and not to my surprise it was at 1 FPS on the menu screen.

#### What I've Tried

I tried reinstalling the system, another version of the driver, and 3 ways of installing the each driver:

- .run file from NVIDIA site.
- From Software & Updates.
- From `ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa`.

Obviously to no avail.

---

And that's when this question comes in, everything is working totally normally on my PC, I didn't try anything else other than games  (e.g. 3D modeling program, Benchmark, Compositor, etc...) but I'm pretty sure they'd have the same effect since all the games I tried did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this is setting the `nomodeset` kernel option after installing the driver.

A good tutorial for Ubunutu for that would be [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/38834/442608).